# HTML/CSS: create two rows with 2 and 3 columns which should take up window viewport and cells should scroll

Tags: html, css

I try to create a simple HTML page layout with basic CSS (no CSS or JS libraries, it should all fit into one HTML file).

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| row1col1 ..................... row1col1         |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
| row2col1 ......  row2col2 ...... row2col3 ..... |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The layout should show two rows of information where the first row has two cells/columns and the second row has 3 columns.

I would like the two rows to take up 60 and 40 percent of the window height, but at least 400px.

The columns in the first row should take up 60 and 40 percent of the window width, but at least 400px;

The columns in the second row should take up 1/3 of the window width, but at least 300px;

But if there are many lines of content in such a column/cell (in either the first or second row) I do NOT want the cell to expand vertically beyond the height of the row, (which should be 60 percent of the window height but at least 400px for the first row and 40 percent of window height but at least 400px for the second row). If there are more rows within a cell, a scrollbar should appear to make them scrollable.

I tried to copy paste some of the solutions to similar problems from SO but nothing I tried worked and there were many very different proposals for how to achieve the several columns per row behavior. It seemed to me that the display styles table, table-row, table-cell etc. fit best for this, but with these I found it impossible to limit the height of a cell or make it scrollable (vertically or horizontally).

I would really want the cells to adapt to the size of the enclosing window or Iframe by the rows and columns taking a certain percentage of the height/width and by the cells using scrollbars if there is more to show but I cannot figure out how to do this.

What I have so far and what does not work is here: https://jsfiddle.net/johann_petrak/cafLqdz5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it using the flex property. Setting the min height and min width to 400px is pretty big and would probably mess up the responsivity that you are looking for.

```css
  .row{
        min-height: 400px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .col{
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 400px;
        min-width: 400px;
        padding: 10px;
        white-space: normal;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="row" style="height:60vh">
        <div class="col" style="width:60%;">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="width:40%;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" style="height:40vh;">
        <div class="col">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @leelum1 this is exactly what I need, learned some interesting things here!